# Timer in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, timer

I was working on a timer code in pure JavaScript and would like to know any pointers to improve:

#### Features

- Start/ Stop/ Reset on click of a button.
- Set limit to clock.
- Update class name for warning and error based on threshold timer.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/0gvfc5yy/11/)

```js
function timer() {
  var time = {
    sec: 00,
    min: 00,
    hr: 00
  };
  var finalLimit = null,
    warnLimit = null,
    errorLimit = null;
  var max = 59;
  var interval = null;

  function init(_hr, _min, _sec) {
    time["hr"] = _hr ? _hr : 0;
    time["min"] = _min ? _min : 0;
    time["sec"] = _sec ? _sec : 0;
    printAll();
  }

  function setLimit(fLimit, wLimit, eLimit) {
    finalLimit = fLimit;
    warnLimit = wLimit;
    errorLimit = eLimit;
  }

  function printAll() {
    print("sec");
    print("min");
    print("hr");
  }

  function update(str) {
    time[str] ++;
    time[str] = time[str] % 60;
    if (time[str] == 0) {
      str == "sec" ? update("min") : update("hr");
    }
    print(str);
  }

  function print(str) {
    var _time = time[str].toString().length == 1 ? "0" + time[str] : time[str];
    document.getElementById("lbl" + str).innerHTML = _time;
  }

  function validateTimer() {
    var className = "";
    var secs = time.sec + (time.min * 60) + (time.hr * 60 * 60);
    if (secs >= finalLimit) {
      stopTimer();
    } else if (secs >= errorLimit) {
      className = "error";
    } else if (secs >= warnLimit) {
      className = "warn";
    }
    var element = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
    document.getElementById("lblsec").className = className;
  }

  function startTimer() {
    init();
    if (interval) stopTimer();
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      update("sec");
      validateTimer();
    }, 1000);
  }

  function stopTimer() {
    window.clearInterval(interval);
  }

  function resetInterval() {
    stopTimer();
    time["sec"] = time["min"] = time["hr"] = 0;
    printAll();
    startTimer();
  }

  return {
    'start': startTimer,
    'stop': stopTimer,
    'reset': resetInterval,
    'init': init,
    'setLimit': setLimit
  }
};

var time = new timer();

function initTimer() {
  time.init(0, 0, 0);
}

function startTimer() {
  time.start();
  time.setLimit(10, 5, 8);
}

function endTimer() {
  time.stop();
}

function resetTimer() {
  time.reset();
}
```

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #fff;
}
.timer {
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.main {
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
.btn {
  -webkit-border-radius: 6;
  -moz-border-radius: 6;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #2980b9;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.btn:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.warn {
  background: yellow;
}
.error {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="timer"> 
      <span id="lblhr">00</span>
    : <span id="lblmin">00</span>
    : <span id="lblsec">00</span>

  </div>
  <button class="btn" onclick="startTimer()">Start</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="endTimer()">Stop</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="resetTimer()">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Vogel612 Thanks. I'll keep that in mind. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It looks really good! Here are a few points;

---

I don't like the arguments in your `setLimit` and `init` functions, especially because some of them are optional.

I would prefer an Object argument in this case.

```
function setLimit(limits) {
  finalLimit = limits.final;
  warnLimit = limits.warn;
  errorLimit = limits.error;
}


this.setLimit({
  final: 10,
  warn: 5,
  error: 8
});
```

This makes it obvious at call time which argument is which.

---

Your var declarations are inconsistent here:

```
var finalLimit = null,
  warnLimit = null,
  errorLimit = null;
var max = 59;
var interval = null;
```

Pick either to comma separate them or not. Not both.

---

In a couple of places you use `==` instead of `===`. Generally we stick to `===` for [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons).

---

You CSS selectors are **very** generic. This is generally a bad thing as they will easily collide with other styles the moment you integrate it into a real page.

I favour [BEM syntax](http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/), which would make it look something like this;

```
<div class="timer">
  <div class="timer__labels"> 
      <span id="timer__hours-label">00</span>
    : <span id="timer__minutes-label">00</span>
    : <span id="timer__seconds-label">00</span>

  </div>
  <button class="timer__btn js-start-timer">Start</button>
  <button class="timer__btn js-end-timer">Stop</button>
  <button class="timer__btn js-reset-timer">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Note I've also removed your `onclick` handlers in favour of interaction specific classes. I prefix my classnames with `js-` if they are used solely for JavaScript selectors. This helps decouple the CSS and JavaScript.

In your code you then attach the handlers;

```
document.querySelectorAll('.js-start-timer')[0]
  .addEventListener('click', startTimer);
```

Comment: Thanks! I would incorporate these points. Also I knew what `==` and `===` do but didn't know its not a good practice to use `==`. Will keep this in mind.

Comment: @Rajesh It's one of those things where sometimes you will need `==`, but generally it's a source of very annoying bugs.

Comment: Is it bad to use `onclick` or other events? I usually find them better. You can read HTML and you know where to look. Problem with event handlers that I feel, when multiple developers are involved, they add multiple event handlers to same element, and this complicates things. Though I'll try to incorporate that as well

Comment: @Rajesh Yeah, generally you want to keep your [JavaScript code separate from your HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). However, the `js-` classes allow me to see exactly what bit of JavaScript will be interacting with that element.

Comment: @Rajesh [Here's a good article about decoupling](http://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/)

Comment: Thanks for articles and also have updated question with incorporated changes you suggested.

Comment: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/0gvfc5yy/12/) with changes